# accessing ipa and plist file from the server behind the IBM webs seal

Tags: iphone, ios, ota

In my OTA i want to access file from the server through itms mechanism of apple.But the files'a are on server and server have IBM webseal security.so when i try to install that files from the server itms do not ask for authentication and hence can not install app.

so please anyone suggest me to access file behind the IBM webseal through itms protocol

Thanks for your reading and help

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue that iTune process doesn't send newly created auth-cookie, thus it can't pass security check.